# Select null values then max value from same column

Tags: sql-server, null, max

```
  OEITEMLONG Workorder Amount Date
               10400     1200   1/1/2017
               10400     1200   2/1/2017
    100000     77777     500    1/2/2017
    99999      77777     -500   1/2/2017
    818181     51515     9500   1/3/2017
```

Need to be able to 1st pull all of the rows with null/blank "OEITEMLONG" in the column.  Then to only pull the MAX value of the "OEITEMLONG" column with a different workorder number.  Our system uses the same workorder numbers, but if a credit is issued, the same workorder number is used, but a higher value "OEITEMLONG" number gets issued and that's what I'm wanting to use along with ALL of the rows with blank "OEITEMLONG" numbers.

```
OEITEMLONG Workorder Amount Date
           10400     1200   1/1/2017
           10400     1200   2/1/2017
100000     77777     500    1/2/2017
818181     51515     9500   1/3/2017
```

This should be the desired result

Thanks,

Comment: Edit your question with desired results as well.  And tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from vWOSEGHEADSmryALL t
where OEITEMLONG is null
union all
select t.*
from vWOSEGHEADSmryALL t
where OEITEMLONG is not null and
      OEITEMLONG = (select max(t2.OEITEMLONG)
                    from vWOSEGHEADSmryALL t2
                    where t2.Workorder = t.Workorder
                   );
```

For your data, this should return:

```
OEITEMLONG Workorder Amount Date
           10400     1200   1/1/2017
           10400     1200   2/1/2017
100000     77777     500    1/2/2017
818181     51515     9500   1/3/2017
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  My table is vWOHEADSmryALL.oeitemlong and vWOHEADSmryALL.workorder, etc.  Can you elaborate a little on how that translates to your t1 and t2 statements in your Select and WHERE clause?  I have 2 Left outer joins after this part that I'm also using.

Comment: `t` refers to the one table you are using.  Your question suggests that there is only one table.

Comment: So t2 is an alias that I would create in the sub query and then reference in the where statement?

Comment: @JBrewer . . . `t2` distinguishes the reference to the table in the subquery from the outer query.

Comment: Understood. I'm not smart enough to follow the part in the last "from" statement where the initial table (t) is followed right after the (t2) table. If my initial table (t) is titled vWOSEGHEADSmryALL and my (t2) table were named Gordon how would that be constructed?  Thanks for the patience!

Comment: @JBrewer . . . Your question only mentions one table.  `t` refers to that table, in all three locations in the query.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm just not following where the t2 alias comes in. You're correct, I just have one table